# Git commands for adding and commiting using bash/shell script

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I'm entirely new to bash scripting, and I'm trying to write a script which adds, commits and pushes into the repository

```
commit_message="$1"
git add . -A
git commit -m "$commit_message"
git push
```

This adds all the edited/new files to my repo, is there a way to pass the required file names as arguments which executing this script?
I got this script from google, but if there is any other way I can do it, please let me know.

Comment: Just leave the add part out, and run that part manually. `git add <files>` / `commit_and_push "message goes here"`. I'm not sure that scripting this is very beneficial.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Save time?

Comment: You can run the script and pass the commit message as argument like `./script.sh "sample message"`

Comment: @RomainValeri it is more inclined towards learning about bash with the things I do on regular basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a function for convenience. It works for my coding style, which for me means always working in a clean directory at the repo root and accessing all files with a relative path. YMMV.

```
qp() {
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "Please enter a commit message:";
    typeset msg="$( [[ -n "$1" ]] && echo "$*" || echo $(head -1) )";
    date;
    git pull;
    git add .;
    git commit -m "$msg";
    git push;
    date
}
```

Call it like -

```
qp add a commit message
```

Note that it flattens all arguments into a single `msg`, and if it gets none it prompts for one.

```
$: qp
Please enter a commit message:
foo bar baz
Tue, Mar 19, 2019  3:25:24 PM
Already up-to-date.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Everything up-to-date
Tue, Mar 19, 2019  3:25:31 PM
```

> ## *What you asked for:*

Rewrite it to take a file list and always ask for the message, like this:

```
qp() {
    echo "Please enter a commit message:";
    typeset msg="$( head -1 )";
    date;
    git pull;
    git add "$@";
    git commit -m "$msg";
    git push;
    date
}
```

You can just put the function code into a script with or without the function as you prefer.

- **NOTE**: you might prefer `cat` to `head -1` to allow multiple lines, but you will have to terminate your message with a CTRL_D or some such.

Then run it as

```
qp file1 file2 fileN
```

and it will ask for the commit message - OR, make the first argument the commit message, like this:

```
qp() {
    typeset msg="$1";
    shift;
    date;
    git pull;
    git add "$@";
    git commit -m "$msg";
    git push;
    date
}
```

Just make sure you **"quote"** that first commit message argument. ;)

```
qp "here's my commit message" file1 file2 fileN
```